# Typescript Map class constructor with initial values not accepting 2 different types

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics

First things first, I'm using these classes:

```
class Student {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  constructor(name: string, age: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

class Food {
  flavor: string;
  portions: number;
  constructor(flavor: string, portions: number) {
    this.flavor = flavor;
    this.portions = portions;
  }
}
```

Basically what I'm doing is that:

```
const food_backpack = new Map<Student, Food>()

const sam = new Student('Sam', 15);
const ariana = new Student('Ariana', 18);

const cheese = new Food('Fetta', 5);
const chocolate = new Food('Twix', 2);

food_backpack.set(sam, cheese);
food_backpack.set(ariana, chocolate);
```

Well that worked.

But I'm trying to use the constructor instead to initialize the map values which IS NOT WORKING for me (compile time errors).
I tried this below:

```
const sam = new Student('Sam', 15);
const ariana = new Student('Ariana', 18);

const cheese = new Food('Fetta', 5);
const chocolate = new Food('Twix', 2);

const bi_sam = [sam, cheese];
const bi_ariana = [ariana , chocolate];

const food_backpack = new Map<Student, Food>([
  bi_sam,
  bi_ariana
]);
```

And this below:

```
const sam = new Student('Sam', 15);
const ariana = new Student('Ariana', 18);

const cheese = new Food('Fetta', 5);
const chocolate = new Food('Twix', 2);

const bi_sam = [(sam as Student) , (cheese as Food)];
const bi_ariana = [(ariana as Student) , (chocolate as Food)];

const food_backpack = new Map<Student | Food, Food | Student>([
  bi_sam,
  bi_ariana
]);
```

Something that uses the constructor way and THAT WORKED is:

```
const sam = new Student('Sam', 15);
const ariana = new Student('Ariana', 18);

const cheese = new Food('Fetta', 5);
const chocolate = new Food('Twix', 2);

const food_backpack = new Map<Student, Food>([
  [sam, cheese], 
  [ariana, chocolate]
]);
```

But I don't prefer it.

Thanks for your precious time and effort!

Comment: What's "NOT WORKING" mean exactly, errors etc

Comment: compile time errors

Comment: Argument of type '(Student | Food)[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReadonlyArray<[Student | Food, Student | Food]>'.
  Type '(Student | Food)[]' is missing the following properties from type '[Student | Food, Student | Food]': 0, 1

Comment: Without a context, like an argument list, to guide inference array types are inferred instead of tuple types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript is unable to match the signature you provided and the one that is passed by the arguments. [Mainly, the values are `readonly` in a `Map`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9569198df6aff00f9d5cfbf4992a0439a9cbf37a/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L31).

You can create a new type like,

```
type StudentRecord = readonly [Student, Food];
```

And now your `Map` constructor should work as intended:

```
const sam = new Student('Sam', 15);
const ariana = new Student('Ariana', 18);

const cheese = new Food('Fetta', 5);
const chocolate = new Food('Twix', 2);

type StudentRecord = readonly [Student, Food];

const bi_sam: StudentRecord = [sam, cheese];
const bi_ariana: StudentRecord = [ariana , chocolate];

const food_backpack = new Map<Student, Food>([
  bi_sam,
  bi_ariana
]);
```

Comment: that I like. Thankss alott!! Btw I saw those weird constructs you’re suggesting but didn’t understand there real purpose until now. I’ll test tomorrow and let you know if all goes to plan.

Comment: Sure thing, you can learn more about how generics work in the [official handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Comment: You can also just write  `const bi_sam = [same, cheese] as const;`

Comment: I tried the 'StudentRecord' and the 'as const' solutions and I still get compile time errors. I'm working on https://repl.it/languages/typescript . Is this compiler outdated?

Comment: Yes, that appears to be running v3.3.3. [readonly Tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#readonly-tuples) were added in v.3.4.

I'd recommend the [official playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) available, it has versions you can switch too.

Answer (score -1):

As we can see at [Map mdn page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map) it takes arguments like this:

```
new Map([
  [1, 'one'],
  [2, 'two'],
  [3, 'three'],
])
```

So it's an array of two-element array. First element is a key and second a value. So it perfectly explain why it works with:

```
new Map<Student, Food>([
  [sam, cheese], 
  [ariana, chocolate]
])
```

but now with:

```
new Map<Student, Food>([
  bi_sam,
  bi_ariana
])
```

Comment: I read that page and that’s what puzzles me. My bi_sam and bi_ariana are just variables representing the exact same thing. I’m starting to get a feel that I’m creating an array of array pointers instead of array of bi-value arrays. What’s your thoughts on that? And why typescript won’t work it out on its own?